# How to trim the content by Words/Letters with (...) and depends on Media screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope everyone doing great. I hope someone can help me to solve this problem. I want to trim my content for example trim it by 30 letters on desktop, 20 on mobile.

Here's my code and it doesn't work

```js
var maxLength = 30;

$('.shorten').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();

    if (text.length > maxLength) {
        var output =/^.{0,30}(?=[\.,; ])\b/.exec(text)[0]
        $(this).text(output + "...");
    }     
});
```

```html
<div class="shorten">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Sint accusantium officia assumenda ea. Laborum in dolorem numquam sapiente. 
    Ea impedit veniam minima facere optio? Repellat officia accusamus quia hic assumenda.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var maxLength = 30
$('.shorten').each(function () {
  var text = $(this).text().trim()

  if (text.length > maxLength) {
    var output = text.slice(0, maxLength)
    $(this).text(output + '...')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shorten">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint 
  accusantium officia assumenda ea. Laborum in dolorem
  numquam sapiente. Ea impedit veniam minima facere optio? Repellat 
  officia accusamus quia hic assumenda.
</div>
```

Comment: Was just about to post this exact solution nice work!